# Why the output is always -1?

Tags: c, unsigned, signed, bit-shift

This is the code:

```
char x=-1>>2;
printf("%d",x);
```

Even if i do `x = -N>>2` it will give `1` only.

```
x = -1 => 11111111 
x= -1>>2 ==> 00111111 = 3F ??
```

Also even if I do int `x = -1>>2` the output will be `1`.

Could you explain how this calculation is carried out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your code will work if you use

```
unsigned char x=-1>>2;
```

For signed numbers (including characters), right shift does not append zeroes. This is called sign bit extension. C uses 2's complement form to store negative numbers. For negative numbers, sign bit (MSB) is 1 in this form which is padded during the operation. Using unsigned number will fix the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Right shift of negative values is implementation defined.

In your case the behaviour of right shift that you are seeing is to preserve the sign.

Consider `char x = -38;`. The following demonstrates how the bitshift works when preserving the sign:

```
x       11011010
x >> 1  11101101
x >> 2  11110110
x >> 3  11111011
etc...
```

Comment: To be pedantic, it's right shifts of *negative values* that are implementation-defined...